# Solution set of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

After computing a matrix with 3 rows and 6 variables I obtained the following.

$x_4$ = $x_2 - 2x_1$

$x_6 = x_1-2x_3$

$x_5=-x_1-2x_2+2x_3$

Rewriting the equation we obtain:

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_2-2x_1, -x_1-2x_2 + 2x_3, x_1-2x_3)$

To this we can factor out our variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and obtain three basis.

I am now asked if the solution set of my system of linear equations produces a plane.

From my understanding 1 vector produces a line, two linearly independent vectors produce a plane, three linearly independent vectors produce $R^3$ and so on.

Therefore am I correct to say that this system of linear equations will not produce a plane it will produce a subspace of Dimension three?

Furthermore, could I have concluded this without any need to compute calculations by saying that 6 variables minus 3 parameters equal a dimension 3? or am I confused.

Thank you

Comment: $\mathbb R^3$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^6$, so no number of elements of the latter can generate $\mathbb R^3$. You should instead say that three independent vectors define a three-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^6$, as you do later.

Comment: The rest is correct yes?

Comment: Yes. Your last question is essentially the Rank-Nullity theorem.

Comment: thank you I'll look further into it.